# Implementing different user interaction function for subviews of a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UICollectionView` which allows for a user to select a cell and upon doing so view 'A' will appear.  I am wondering if it is possible for the subviews of this cell, ex: `UIlabel` and `UIImageView` to provide a different functionality for when they alone are selected.  For example, if the `UIImageView` is selected, I want to segue to view 'B' as opposed to 'A'.

I have attempted to implement a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for both the label and the image, however, the cell's functionality overrules and the resulting view is still 'A'.  Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is possible through delegates if you don't have custom cell make a custom cell class then inside custom cell declare your protocol

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have to disable the default behavior of the collection view cells:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
```

However, if you set that and you encounter an overlap issue, please take a look at the 'cancelTouchesInView' property of the 'UITapGestureRecognizer'. Basically, by setting that to false, you allow the children to also receive touch actions.

Furthermore, do not forget each gesture recognizer should have it's own method for you to be able to segue into two different places.